# Is there a toolkit that will provide a web-based API (xmlrpc, REST, whatever) to remote IMAP servers?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, imap

I'm working on a Google App Engine project that needs to access IMAP. Context.IO isn't quite powerful enough for my purposes, but I'd like something in the same spirit: I want to log into, access, and manipulate hundreds of IMAP mailboxes from within Google App Engine, using either a third-party service or an application server I put on a dedicated hosting server.

As you might imagine, this is mostly to work around the opening sockets limitation in GAE.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any pre-made solution, but rolling your own shouldn't be very difficult or take too long. You can build on [IMAPClient](http://imapclient.freshfoo.com/) and [SimpleXMLRPCServer](http://docs.python.org/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html) on the server and use [xmlrpclib](http://docs.python.org/library/xmlrpclib.html) on the client.

You would need to think about a way to retain state between calls though, since XmlRPC  is a connectionless protocol (as most other RPC mechanisms are as well) and implement some form of service authentication. I have written a class inherited from `SimpleXMLRPCServer`, which supports SSL connections and HTTP Basic Auth (`xmlrpclib` already has support for both items). If you're interested in the code, give me a shout.

Comment: Thanks. That's actually what I ended up doing, though I used gocept's object-oriented IMAP implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Mailgun](http://mailgun.net/); it offers a robust API and supports IMAP V4.<sup>*</sup>

<sup>* IMAP mailboxes are on Mailgun</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the link. Almost. Unfortunately while mailgun appears to support reading mailboxes it hosts, there isn't a function to go access arbitrary ones out on the web.